# Why does my .click() only work when I scroll my mouse?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the data in the expanded container "resulted".

My code below only works when I manually scroll my mouse.  If I don't touch my mouse, the container does not expand and I can't scrape the text.

Please give me direction as to how I can expand the container without manually scrolling my mouse wheel.

My code below

```
target_url = "https://www.racenet.com.au/form-guide/horse-racing/the-valley-20231006/breast-cancer-network-australia-handicap-race-5/overview"

driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 220)")

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-header')))
  

element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value= 'event-header')
element.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10)
```

Comment: To automate scrolling and expand the container, you can use the `ActionChains` class in Selenium to simulate a scroll action.

Comment: Thanks chankruze, I tried moving to element but I'm getting a "ElementNotInteractableException" error

# create action chain object 
    action = ActionChains(driver) 
  
# perform the operation 
    action.move_to_element(element)
    element.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10)

Comment: Okay, I am writing an answer for you, in the mean time can you please update the question with some screenshots of the element you want to expand and the content you want to extract by marking them on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't expand because selenium doesn't wait until the element on view in this case you can use `sleep` from `time` module.

```py
from time import sleep
# rest of the imports

target_url = "https://www.racenet.com.au/form-guide/horse-racing/the-valley-20231006/breast-cancer-network-australia-handicap-race-5/overview"

driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 220)")
sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-header')))
  
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value= 'event-header')
element.click()

# rest of the code
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  I thought the webdriverwait was performing the same function as the sleep. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

target_url = "https://www.racenet.com.au/form-guide/horse-racing/the-valley-20231006/breast-cancer-network-australia-handicap-race-5/overview"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200);")

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-header')))

time.sleep(2)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-header')))

element.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```